# how do i make a bunch of words into a list?

Tags: python, string

I've got a random bunch of words and I need to make it into a list, but there is a problem, I must take the words as they are and convert them into a list in the program itself.
for example I got this raw input:

```
hello,mike,cat,dog,burger
```

Now how do i take this 5 words and make my program to make each word into a proper string like so: "hello","mike","cat","dog","burger"

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `split` method

```
>>> s = "hello,mike,cat,dog,burger"
>>> l = s.split(',')
>>> l
['hello', 'mike', 'cat', 'dog', 'burger']
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning `l = [item.strip() for item in s.split(',')]` in case of spaces after the coma?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
the_string = '"hello","mike","cat","dog","burger"'
the_list = the_string.split(",") # split on a literal comma
```

Note that this requires that the user properly format the string, and that there are no leading or trailing spaces (e.g. `Hello, dog` becomes `["Hello", " dog"]`). Consider building some sanity tests for the string, and possibly mapping the whole thing through [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)